# Image size difference while saving and sending in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-bitmap

My image in activity1 getting saved in internal storage with size of 5.8kb and I send the same image from same activity using extra stream of intent and it becomes 15kb at receiver's end. What is the logic behind this?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
        intent.setType("imge/png");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to); //user entered email address in edittext view.
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
        startActivity(intent);
        saveImage(bmap);

    public void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap){
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/My Folder");
    String receiverN = receiverName.getText().toString();

    myDir.mkdirs();
    //name convention--------------------------------------------->>
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String month, day, year, hour, minute, second;
    month = ""+ (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
    day = "" + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    year = "" + c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    hour = ""+c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    if(hour.equals("0")) hour = "0"+hour;
    minute = "" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    if (seconds<10) second = "0"+ seconds;
    else second = ""+seconds;

    String fname = receiverN + "-" + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + "_"  + month + "-" + day + "-" + year +".png";
    //name convention ends----------------------------------------->>

    File file = new File (myDir, fname);


    if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        String[] paths = {file.toString()};
        String[] mimeTypes = {"/image/png"};
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MyClass.this, paths, mimeTypes, null);
        Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code for intent extra stream which takes my bitmaps URI and sends the image properly and save method is also there. Saves as 5.8kb 960*960 and sends as 15kb, 960*960. I want same size both the times.

Comment: Could you post the implement of `extra stream of intent`?

Comment: added code, hope this will be clear..

Comment: Which mail app does it open? Have you tried other mail app? Bitmap may be compressed in receiver end with different algorithm.

Comment: I am opening with Gmail and attached image size shows 15kb...

Comment: Are you sure, I did the same in my Phone? I don't think Gmail compresses the image

Comment: not compressing its augmenting the size I believe, from 5.8kb to 15kb..

Comment: How do you get the number 5.8kb? If it is from the file system, you can do nothing.

Comment: I save the image with saveImage method and it saves in internal storage thus I can see the details and it shows 5.8kb there...

Answer (score 0):

In saveImage(Bitmap bitmap)method you have used "bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out)"

Based on the parameter you have used in the compress method, the size of the image will vary. Quality of the image can be set from 0(Low) to 100(High). If you update the quality, the size of the image can be maintained.

Comment: update the quality means to change the integer value in the variable?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the value between 0 and 100 according to your needs. 0 refers low quality and 100 refers high quality.

Comment: No, quality will be ignored if you compress to PNG format.

Comment: see the quality parameter document of [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream))

Comment: If you compress to a png format there would not be any use in changing the integer value,whereas it has an effect on the bitmap size only when you compress to JPEG format.There is no way that the bitmap stored and bitmap mailed would differ in size...Here is my link for the code that i have tried.. [Github] (https://github.com/MallowTech/ImageCompressionSample)

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is correct. To check that, just use your method saveImage() before sending image.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    String[] paths = {file.toString()};
    String[] mimeTypes = {"/image/png"};
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MyClass.this, paths, mimeTypes, null);
    Toast.makeText(MyClass.this, "Image Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**UPDATE:**

[Some understanding files size in different systems and OS.](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/for-the-same-file-why-windows-and-ubuntu-show-different-sizes/)

Comment: How come? Image is saved as 5.8KB with 100 as Quality, the same image the user sends through Gmail which increases the size of the Image.

Comment: exactly thats happening... this image saved in internal storage as 5.8kb and as 15kb while sending via gmail... giving me lots of headache... trying to find out everywhere but resizing researchs are there but not same sized one...